# Can't seem to ever get the print function in linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

cant print the linked list, it gets stuck in an infinite loop cant understand where i'm going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{

    int data;
    struct node *next;

}node;

node *head = NULL;

void print(node *head){

    node *temp = head;

    while(temp!=NULL);
    {
        printf("%d => ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("NULL");

}

node *clist(int n){

    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        printf("Enter the elements of the list.\n");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
    }

    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        while(p->next!=NULL)
        p=p->next; //shifting p here node by node

        p->next = temp; //last node which was just created
    }

    else
    {
        head = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

node *binsert(int x){

    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        temp->next = head;
        temp = head;
    }

    else
    {
        p = head = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

int main ()
{
    int a, s, i, n,f;

    printf("Choose an option : \n1.Create a list.\n2.Exit.\n");
    scanf("%d",&s);

    switch(s)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("Very Well! Input the number of nodes\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            head = clist(n);
            printf("Link List created successfully.\n");
            print(head);
            break;

        default:
            exit (0);           
    }

    printf("Choose the operation you want to perform on the linked list:\n1.Add an element to the beginning.\n2.Add an element to the end.\n3.Add an element at a a particular position.\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the element you want to insert at the beginning.\n");
            scanf("%d",&f);

            binsert(f);
            printf("Inserted Successfully.\n");
            print(head);

            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Error E162B");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I tried changing the head to a global variable. re-wrote the code 7 times. please help.

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger?  What's `p` for in your `binsert` function?

Comment: You need to compile your code on the highest warning level, make sure you've removed all the warnings. Once you've done that, load the program in your debugger and single-step through it. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. You'll finish your assignment faster, and you'll learn a lot about how code works.

Comment: Take a very careful look at your `clist` function. You create `n` temp nodes but they aren't ever linked to anything. You need to do that in the for loop.

Comment: Your endless loop is partly because of an incorrect semicolon at the end of this line: `while (temp != NULL);` If you fix the list creation and remove that semicolon you should be all set. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("Enter the elements of the list.\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp->data);
}
```

This loop repeats several times so that the user can enter the elements of the list. But it never adds any of the nodes to the linked list. Each iteration of the loop changes `temp` to point to a newly-allocated node but doesn't add the nodes to the linked list.

Second:

```
while(temp!=NULL);
```

This is an endless loop right here. If `temp` is not `NULL`, it's not changed anywhere in the loop, so it will never become `NULL`. You don't want that semicolon there.

Third:

```
node *head = NULL;

void print(node *head){

   node *temp = head;
```

Don't do this to yourself. You have a global variable called `head` and you have a parameter called `head`. When you do `node *temp = head;` how obvious is it *which* `head` that's referring to. Don't give two variables the same name if their scope overlaps.

Fourth:

```
if(head!=NULL)
{
    temp->next = head;
    temp = head; // **** here
}

else
{
    p = head = temp;
}

return head;
```

What's the point of `temp = head;`? The value of `temp` isn't accessed anywhere. So that can't be right.

Lastly:

I think you didn't ask the right question though. You asked us to explain where you're going wrong, and I've done that. But I don't think that's what you actually need. Maybe you need help developing the algorithm to solve the problem? Perhaps ask a new question describing what you think the algorithm should be (just in words, no need to use code) and ask for help fixing the algorithm.

And, to be blunt, the number of mistakes suggests that you are attempting a task that is significantly beyond your knowledge. This is frustrating and not a good way to learn programming. You should seriously consider attempting simpler tasks first.

You may have stripped it out to keep the question simple, but your real code should contain *lots* of extra checking and logging to help you understand it. Log when you enter a function. Log each decision the function makes. Log what functions return. That will help you determine where the program's actual operation is deviating from you think it should be doing. Or, if you prefer, learn to use your platform's debugging facilities. That way, you won't be making random changes and hoping that they make everything work but will instead know where the code is first going awry and be able to fix one thing at a time confident that you are not breaking things that were working.